# How to pipe audio output to mic input

Tags: audio, alsa

I've looked all over the internet for a clean way to reroute the audio output of my computer (i.e. what I'd hear from the speaker) to my microphone's input.

Possibly, I'd like to do this at a low level (e.g. using [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture)).

I'm basically looking for an equivalent of

```
pacmd move-sink-input #index #sink
```

that gets some audio input and pipes it to the microphone.

If it's still not clear my final goal would be, for example, to play a video on YouTube and let a friend of mine listen through Skype. I'd like that kind of flexibility.

Comment: Have you tried [jackaudio](http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/virtual-audio-cable-linux-and-windows.html)?

Comment: no, what's the name of the package (using apt-get)?

Comment: ah, try `apt-get install projectm-jack`

Comment: I asked a similar question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558149/play-audio-output-as-input-to-zoom, that is different than this answer in that my app, Zoom, does not do recording.

Comment: How do I get audio to work in gtk-recordmydesktop with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82297/546389)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you can do this with PulseAudio. I found this tutorial that shows how, titled: [Redirect Audio Out to Mic In (Linux)](https://www.kirsle.net/redirect-audio-out-to-mic-in-linux).

#### General Steps

1. Run the application `pavucontrol`.
2. Go to the "Input Devices" tab, and select "Show: Monitors" from the bottom of the window. If your computer is currently playing audio, you should see a bar showing the volume of the output:

   [image: ss of pauvucontrol #1]
3. Now start an application that can record audio such as `audacity` and record audio (red point icon in audacity).
4. In `pavucontrol` (Volume Control) change to the `Recording` tab.
5. Click the input device button ("ALSA Capture from") and pick "Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo")

[image: ss of pauvucontrol #2]

Comment: all right, I can't mix inputs but apart from that it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: To mix inputs i think you may need jack. It enables one to tunnel almost any output or input to other places, filters, etc

Comment: Thanks, I used it to play Ivona from firefox to TeamSpeak :D

Comment: Does not work if the application set custom sink along with `sink_dont_move`: monitor devices aren't usually listed by applications when selecting input device (eg. Zoom)