# Trying to record from the default audio source

Tags: audio, screencasting

I am trying to record the sound output, but this looks more complicated than expected.

I expected that

```
 arecord -f cd -t wav --max-file-time 3600 --use-strftime %Y/%m/%d/listen-%H-%M-%v.wav
```

would record 1 file every hour, putting the resulting file in a directory structure with year, month, day and name (hour).wav file.

It actually records the sound output through the microphone (adding to it every imaginable environment noise, specially typing in the keyboard).

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 800x600 -i :0.0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k  /tmp/outputFile.mpg` manages to record the video and sound, but suffers from the same problem as the previous command.

Is there a way of pipping  to a file the sound that's being generated?

The output of `record -l` is:

> List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ** card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

If I don't find a solution, I'd go with the inelegant solution of buying a loopback cable to connect the output of the loudspeakers to the input of the microphone.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? [how to pipe audio output to mic input](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input/82297#82297)

Comment: @slm: nope. I want to record the conversation partner of mine in a voip conversation, with video and audio.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the linked questions, it will allow you to set up a recording source from the audio output. Then you use your `ffmpeg` command to record the video, and use either the ffmpeg command or `pavucontrol` to set it to record from the source you just created.

Comment: @user4186: now that I see it calmly I realize that slm was right. That's what I wanted.