# Pulseaudio recording device setting not sticking

Tags: pulseaudio, chrome

I'm trying to use `pavucontrol` to set the recording device of Google Chrome to the output device monitor using the steps provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input#answer-82297), but it always switches back within a couple seconds. the 'recording' tab has a visible refresh every 2-3 seconds and that setting always changes back. I can change the device just fine for other programs such as Audacity.

I commented the line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and restarted pulse / rebooted, no luck.

Here is a video demonstrating my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMcwC.jpg

I would like to use [Web Captioner](https://webcaptioner.com) to caption what my friends are saying in Discord because I am hearing impaired. It uses the Web Speech API which is only available in Google Chrome. I am open to trying other tools such as JACK.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.