# PulseAudio command to pass application output audio to mic input

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I am looking for a pulseaudio command (i.e. `pactl` or `pacmd`) to pass any sound that is played by one particular application to my mic input.

Example: I am using a music player app. I want the music that I hear to also go through my PC audio input that is usually picking up my microphone instead.

EDIT: A similar question was asked here, [How to pipe audio output to mic input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input), but the answer involves using pavucontrol, which is an extra utility I'd rather not install. If it can be done from the pavucontrol ui, surely there is a direct pacmd way of achieving similar behavior, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pipe audio output to mic input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sort of? I did already see this post, but I don't use pavucontrol as my pulseaudio controller; I already use and enjoy pulsemixer. So ideally, I'd like a way to do this from the command line and not have to install a second controller application just for the one single purpose.